# Can not login to Github on browser, but works fine when use vpn or login on Github Desktop

Tags: authentication, github

I'm get message: "There have been several failed attempts to sign in from this account or IP address.

Please wait a while and try again later." when login to github on browser.

But it working fine when I'm use vpn or login on github desktop.

I have reset my modem to get new ip, but it's still not working on browser.
Any body know reason?

Comment: Just FYI, I reset my password and signed in again using email instead of username and it works again.